# Query regarding surprising Behavior in Controlled operations in QDK

Tags: quantum-computing

I have been learning QDK and I observe the provided output for the following program:

Program:
'''

```
operation BitIsOne( qs : Qubit[] ): Unit is  Adj+Ctl
{
    Message( "Is One" );
    X(qs[0]);                                        // added in update
}

operation BitIsZero( qs: Qubit[] ): Unit is Adj+Ctl
{
    Message( "Is Zero" );
}

operation RandomBehavior( qs: Qubit[] ) : Unit is Adj+Ctl
{
    X( qs[0] );
    Controlled BitIsZero( [qs[0]], Rest( qs ) );
    X( qs[0] );
    Controlled BitIsOne( [qs[0]], Rest( qs ) );
    DumpMachine("");                                 // added in update
}
 
operation TestFunc3() : Unit is Adj+Ctl
{
    using( qs = Qubit[3] )
    {
        RandomBehavior( qs[0..1] );  
    }
}

@EntryPoint()
operation Start2() : Unit {
    Message(" Started Execution");
    TestFunc3();
}
```

Output:

```
Started Execution
Is Zero
Is One
```

I do not understand why is **Is One** printed here? The input qubit i thought were 00, so why did the second controlled operation execute the *BitIsOne* function?

**Update to provide requested info that supports explanation in Answer**
(Code edits to get info and confirm explanation included)

[image: Output of DumpMachine. Had changed the BitIsOne function to include X(qs[0]). This shows that the quantum operation did not execute in the else part but the classical function "Message" did execute.]

Had changed the *BitIsOne* function to include X(qs[0]). This shows that the quantum operation did not execute in the else part but the classical function "Message" did execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try measuring the qubits at the end and share the result. Should be 00, in spite of what got printed. "Control" in quantum does not behave like a classical IF statement, in that both the "THEN" part and the "ELSE" part get "executed". The non-quantum "Message" statement gets "executed" in the "ELSE" part, even though in quantum terms the "ELSE" part is a "No-Op" (Identity).

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev for the explanation. So a X gate, in the else part, as you mentioned does not get executed. Included the findings as an update in the question itself.